# Is maths or math the shortened form on the site?

Tags: discussion

Are both shortened forms (British and American) of mathematics acceptable?

Comment: I assume people will know what you mean either way...!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think there's a need to enforce a specific dialect on the site. Math, maths, color, colour - as long as everyone knows what you mean, I don't see any problem.